# How to hide only the actionbar on selection of a text in edittext

Tags: android

I am working on a project in which I have to select a text on long press. It works but the action bar appears. I want to hide the action bar but not selection of the text in edittext box. I have searched for it but didn't get any specific answer.

Comment: where do you have edittext?

Comment: It is in a fragment. I have tried getActivity().getActionBar().hide() but it is not working..

Answer (score 1):

In the onclick method put this line...

```
getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
```

Also, a little tip. I like to define a variable called `appContext` and I make it equal `this` in the `onCreate` method so I can use the application's context easily.

Comment: I have tried getActivity().getActionBar().hide(); on longclick but it is not working...

Comment: @Clay there is no such method getApplicationContext().getActionBar()... getActionBar() method is defined in Activity, not in ApplicationContext... edit your answer...

Comment: @user2119884 ok, sorry, I dont know the answer

Answer (score 0):

so hard to undstand what you mind , I think you should try this :

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```